# What ip address shall I use? public IP or private ip?

Tags: ip, aws

In AWS environment, we usually have two ip address, public one and private one. 
When we login on to the host, we use public ip, and we edit hosts file, we use private ip, is it right? What is the best practice of this?

```
hostname;    private ip;   public ip;
host1        192.168.1.2   202.118.2.117
host2        192.168.1.3   202.118.2.118
host3        192.168.1.4   202.118.2.119
host4        192.168.1.5   202.118.2.120
host5        192.168.1.6   202.118.2.121
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Unix & Linux; it would probably be a better fit for SuperUser.

Comment: Depends what you're editing your hosts file for... Also, it's probably a better fit for ServerFault, maybe. Or maybe Webmasters SE. Or Networking, lol! Again, depending on what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: Maybe it is not here...However I have seen so much confusion due to hosts misconfiguration, than even I am not particular sure it belongs here or not - every sysadmin should be aware of these details. My "favourite" was a hosts file of a web frontend with the NAT address of the Linux MySQL server...and they not noticing the SQL connections where going back and forth in the infra-structure, and "it was slow". Why a MySQL should have a public address, that is a special consideration for another day. The hosts should have at least the private address normally

Comment: You can also use the provided DNS record. This will automatically select internal IP if you're connecting from AWS.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, for internal services use the private IP address, for services with outside visibility use the public IP address.

So, any communication between local servers in the same network will be using the private IP address (e.g. for instance the webfrontend communicating with a mySQL server); any services being given to the outside you use the public IP address (a web virtual host for instance).

In the hosts file, it is imperative to use the private IP address, however you *might* use both a hostname with the private and a DNS name with the public IP address. At the end of the day, it also depends on your setup.